# Declaring a variable and assigning with move assignment operator in one statement on Clang causes seg fault

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, clang, move

I've got this trivial example of what I thought was calling the move assignment operator of this Test struct. Running it, it calls the move constructor and then seg faults on destruction on Clang. On MSVC, it works fine.

I'm a bit confused by that behavior cause i would expect it to construct with the parameterless constructor and then call the move assignment operator.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Test
{
Test() : data(nullptr), dataCount(0) {}

Test(Test&& other)
{
  std::cout << "mv cstr" << std::endl << std::flush;
  delete[] data;
  data = other.data;
  other.data = nullptr;

  dataCount = other.dataCount;
}

Test& operator=(Test&& other)
{
  std::cout << "mv op" << std::endl << std::flush;
  
  delete[] data;
  data = other.data;
  other.data = nullptr;

  dataCount = other.dataCount;
  return *this;
}

~Test()
{
  std::cout << "dstr " << (void*)this << std::endl << std::flush; 
  delete[] data;
  data = nullptr;
}

char* data;
size_t dataCount;
};

int main() {
    Test test;
    test.data = new char[3];
    test.dataCount = 3;

    Test newTest = std::move(test);
    return 0;
}
```

If I instead declare and then assign, it of course works as expected

```cpp
int main() {
    Test test;
    test.data = new char[3];
    test.dataCount = 3;

    Test newTest;
    newTest = std::move(test);
    return 0;
}
```

I've read through the std::move, move assignment operator, and move constructor documentation a few times but I'm just not getting what's specifically different here or left up to the compilers that would give different behavior between MSVC and Clang.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your move constructor begins with `delete[] data;` which is a deletion of an uninitialized member variable.

Comment: *What am I missing?* -- The debugger should have pointed you to the `delete [] data;` that is at issue.  As far as MSVC, if you are running a "debug" version, more than likely that `data` was set to `nullptr` by the debug runtime, thus you didn't encounter the problem.

Comment: That totally makes sense on the move constructor. But why does the move constructor get called at all? Why doesnt the move assignment operator get called instead? I thought `Test newTest(std::move(test))` would be the only way to call the move constructor. Why does `Test newTest = std::move(test)` call the move constructor? Ill do a test tomorrow, but i was pretty sure in MSVC that it was calling the assignment operator

Comment: @Droydn `Test newTest = std::move(test);` -- You are not reading the entire line of code here.  This calls the move constructor because you are constructing a new object.  Anytime you see `Object T = whatever;`, construction is taking place, no matter what `whatever` happens to be.  The `=` is not assignment in this case.

Comment: Also, as far as MSVC goes, when run on Visual Studio 2019, debug build, it halts with an exception violation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The move constructor is going to be called, because that is exactly what the code you wrote is designed to do:

```
Test newTest = std::move(test);
```

There is no move assignment happening here, since a new object, `newTest`, is being constructed from the value on the right side of the `=`.

Since your move constructor has a call to `delete[] data;` and `data` is not initialized, *undefined behavior* occurs.

> i would expect it to construct with the parameterless constructor and
> then call the move assignment operator.

If you think about this, this should not be expected.  The compiler isn't going to take a circuitous route like this to construct the object, causing an unnecessary slow down.

What if the default constructor was "heavy", i.e. went through expensive operations to construct the object?  The whole point of the move constructor is to not have to go through this step, and to simply "steal" the data from the object being moved from.